# Creating a list of a provided type in F#

Tags: types, f#, type-providers

I am trying to add a basic JSON type provider to [fsharpx](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx).
At the moment I am struggeling with JSON Arrays. Consider the following test case:

```
type SimpleArray = JSON< "{\"items\":[{\"id\":\"Open\"},{\"id\":\"Pause\"}]}">

let a = SimpleArray()

[<Test>] 
let ``Can parse simple arrays``() = 
    a.items.[0].id
    |> should equal "Open"

    a.items.[1].id
    |> should equal "Pause"
```

The idea is that I want to use the first element in the array to get the type of the collection elements. Then I want to add a property "items" to the SimpleArray type that gives a list of this new type.

The code can be found in the github repo [Github](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx/blob/TypeProviders/src/FSharpx.TypeProviders/JsonProvider.fs). The interesting part starts at line 38. As you can see the whole thing has to be recursive since the JArray could also contain nested JArrays.

```
| JArray list ->
    let newType = annotateAsJson list.[0] (runtimeType<obj> (ownerTy.Name + "_" + e.Key))
    ownerTy.AddMember newType
    Some(provideProperty
            e.Key
            newType // TODO: make this a list
            (fun args -> Expr.Coerce(<@@ (%%args.[0] : obj) @@>, newType)) // TODO: return the list
            :> MemberInfo)
```

Thanks,
Steffen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's the question, exactly?  It looks like you need to provide multiple types (e.g. in your example you've got the outer type containing `items` and then an inner type containing `id`).  You probably want the inner type to be a nested type within the outer type.  Then you make the provided `items` property contain a list of the inner type.  Is there a particular aspect of that which you are having trouble with?

**EDIT**

If it's just that you are wondering how to create the `Type` instance itself, have you tried

```
typedefof<_ list>.MakeGenericType(newType)
```

This presumes that the underlying value it itself an `obj list`, which is necessary since `newType` erases to `obj`.

Comment: Thanks. The type seems to be fixed now. But I'm still having trouble to return the list. I'm getting InvalidCastException from string to FSharpList<Object>.

Comment: @forki23 - It looks like you're pattern matching against `JArray list` and then never using `list` in the definition of the property.  Perhaps use `list` instead of `args.[0]` in the expression you're building?

Comment: Yep. That's really weird. Even if I replace this I still don't get it working. I'm missing something here.